# Criar selects com hibernate criteria generico

Tags: hibernate, arquitetura-de-software, java, criteria

Estou fazendo um software web, administrativo, ele tem vários gráficos e varias tabelas, o problema com isso é que vários gráficos e tabelas geram muitas consultas ao banco de dados, e com isso, muitas classes que tem uma estrutura parecida, por exemplo, para os gráficos todos possuem o atributo data, um array de inteiros ou de datas, gostaria de escrever um código mais elegante, fazendo com que com apenas uma classe de repositório pudesse trazer os valores de datas genericamente, cheguei a criar uma unica classe usando o java Generics que faz as operações básicas para cada entidade do banco(select, update, delete, lista...), ficou bem melhor, funciona bem e me reduziu umas 500 linhas de código(são 18 entidades...), gostaria de fazer algo assim para os datas.

Como sou novo com hibernate, estou encontrando dificuldades em visualizar como posso fazer isso de forma genérica, pode ser que haja uma API que já faça isso... aceito qualquer coisa para melhorar o código. E é claro, essa é uma boa opção? implementar uma classe genérica para todos os gráficos ou uma classe para cada?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, qual seria sua dificuldade ao criar essa classe generica? Seria a Query?

Comment: o método vai retornar um arry de int (int[]) só que cada gráfico tem seu próprio array, ou seja, um único método, todos os arrays, preciso saber qual array devolver... e alem disso cada select feito dentro do banco agrupo de diferentes tabelas e de diferentes agrupamentos e tal... quero um genérico único que traga de forma simples a solução e devolva o array. É bem confuso...

Comment: Você pensou em usar interface? Você poderá usar ela para o hibernate e cada relatório poderá ter uma implementação.

Comment: Estive pensando em outra maneira de fazer o que você quer e cheguei nesse exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/173937/60946. Veja se ajuda em algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe o [uaiCriteria](http://uaicriteria.com/), um Framework para JPA. Não creio que seja uma solução completa ao seu problema, mas é uma alternativa para simplificar o código.

Por exemplo, para obter uma lista de `Pessoa` com o nome `José`:

```
final UaiCriteria uaiCriteria = UaiCriteriaFactory.createQueryCriteria(entityManager, Pessoa.class);
uaiCriteria.andEquals("nome", "José");
final List uaiCriteriaResult = uaiCriteria.getResultList();
```

Comment: Bem legal essa API,  mas ainda não resolve o problema como você mesmo disse, ainda sim é a unica resposta, caso não apareça nada, vou marca-la como solução, considerando que ela resolve parte do problema...