# Consulta dinâmica usando JPQL

Tags: java, jsf, criteria, padrão-dao

Preciso implementar uma lógica de consulta dinâmica, no BD usando JPQL, sendo que tenho 4 filtros:

> 1 - COORDENADOR DO PROJETO
>   2 - FORNECEDOR DO SERVIÇO
>   3 - DATA INICIO DO PROJETO
>   4 - DATA FINAL DO PROJETO

Qualquer um dos campos pode ser combinados entre si, isto é, pode ser selecionado COORDENADOR e DATA INICIAL, FORNECEDOR e DATA INICIAL, e assim por diante...

As tabelas estão sendo gerenciadas pelos respectivos Entities:

> ProjetoEntity contem o attributo "coordenador" 
>   PlanoEntregaEntity contem o atributo "fornecedor" 
>  EntregaEntity
>   contem o atributo "datainicial" e "datafinal".

Tentei implementar Criteria (uaihebert, easycriteria, criteriabuilder e etc), mas não tive muito sucesso, se alguém tiver alguma indicação, mesmo wue inicial, ficarei grato.

Comment: Mas essa pesquisa vai retornar uma lista de qual entidade (ProjetoEntity, PlanoEntregaEntity ou EntregaEntity)?

Answer (score 1):

Vou deixar uma idéia que você pode tentar aprimorar. O hibernate possui um recurso que permite criar uma consulta a partir de uma instância: [org.hibernate.criterion.Example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/pt-BR/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-examples). Como você já possui as entidades, basta setar os valores que você quer pesquisar na própria entidade e criar uma função para recebê-la como parâmetro e retornar um Criterion para usar nas consultas. Segue o exemplo abaixo:

```
public Criterion criarCriteria(Object projeto) {
    Criterion retorno = null;
    if (projeto != null) {
        retorno = Example.create(projeto)
                        .ignoreCase()
                        .enableLike(MatchMode.ANYWHERE);
    }
    return retorno;
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<ProjetoEntity> consultarProjeto(ProjetoEntity projeto, PlanoEntregaEntity planoEntrega, EntregaEntity entrega) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(ProjetoEntity.class);

    Criterion criterionProjeto = this.criarCriteria(projeto);
    if (criterionProjeto != null) {
        criteria.add(criterionProjeto);
    }

    Criterion criterionPlanoEntrega = this.criarCriteria(planoEntrega);
    if (criterionPlanoEntrega != null) {
        DetachedCriteria criteriaPlanoEntrega = DetachedCriteria.forClass(PlanoEntregaEntity.class);
        criteriaPlanoEntrega.add(criterionPlanoEntrega);
        criteriaPlanoEntrega.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
        criteria.add(Property.forName("planoEntrega").in(criteriaPlanoEntrega));
    }

    Criterion criterionEntrega = this.criarCriteria(entrega);
    if (criterionEntrega != null) {
        DetachedCriteria criteriaEntrega = DetachedCriteria.forClass(EntregaEntity.class);
        criteriaEntrega.add(criterionEntrega);
        criteriaEntrega.setProjection(Projections.property("id"));
        criteria.add(Property.forName("entrega").in(criteriaEntrega));
    }

    return criteria.getExecutableCriteria(this.getSession()).list();
}
```